# Workaround for createrepo without placing the SQLite DB on NFS?

Tags: sqlite, centos7, yum, nfs

I want to build a local YUM repository on (my) NFS so it does not take up space of the host and others can access it. When I try to create a repository in the NFS directories I got the follow error.

```
[root@d62539456920 /]# createrepo /data/docker-ce-stable/ -g comps.xml
Could not create exclusive lock in /data/docker-ce-stable/repodata and sqlite database generation enabled. Is this path on nfs? Is your lockd running?
```

Has any one worked out a way where you can have `createrepo` use the directories without placing the SQLite DB in the NFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build using a temporary folder and then sync/copy the sqlite folder (repodata) back into place on your nfs share. eg:

```
createrepo path_to_repo_folder -o /tmp
rsync -a --delete /tmp/repodata/ path_to_repo_folder/repodata/
```

You might want to sync both ways if you have a large repo and are using --update

Answer (score 1):

You can mount the NFS mount with the nolock option.   I too was having the same issue and it seems to have worked.

example for autofs:

```
/mnt/sata/software         -fstype=nfs,nolock,soft  10.0.0.251:/storage/sata/files/software
```